# Wordpress Featured Image Not Uploading Image To Server

Tags: php, wordpress

So I used the codes below in the functions.php

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post'));
set_post_thumbnail_size(100, 100);
```

And then in THE LOOP, I called:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

The image has an entry in the **database** with its URL but the file isn't uploaded when I checked in the **wp-content/uploads/** directory.

What am I doing wrong?

1. I have no plug-ins installed.
2. Everything is commented out in my .htaccess (by default, it was like this) I am still in my local machine anyway.

Comment: Does the apache user have write access to the uploads folder? Is there more info in your PHP error log?

Comment: I am using ubuntu and my permissions are like this: 

drwxrwxr-x 3 www-data www-data uploads